# How could I fix this error when downloading PhoneGap (file could not be found)

Tags: cordova, mobile-development

I am currently trying to install PhoneGap (Cordova) onto my computer. I thought I was out of the woods when all of a sudden this popped up (I included the command I typed in).

```
~$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

Hopefully you guys can help me out here.     -Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I don't understand - what does installing those packages have to do with installing PhoneGap?  You install PhoneGap by installing Node & NPM, then executing the following command:

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Comment: First off I would like to thank you for taking interest in my question. Second off, if I am not mistaken, I believe that that specific command was to download the libraries on which without PhoneGap cannot run. Here is the link off of which I got this information : dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797

Comment: Dear @johnwargo please help me. I need this to create my app. I used to use android studio but I couldn't use any of the premade pages because of an installation error. If anyone knows how to fix this, please help.

Comment: OK, next time, best to identify the platform you're working on. Ubuntu is not a very popular platform for Cordova development. You should use the instructions on the Cordova Ubuntu platform guide at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/index.html. That's what I used to configure my Ubuntu development environment when I wrote my last Cordova book. Are you doing Cordova or PhoneGap? If PhoneGap, why? Any special reason you picked PhoneGap over Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you required to install node version according to your system from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

After installing node you can use the "npm".
And using it you can install phonegap, cordova.

if you are using windows

> npm install -g phonegap

And for ubuntu and mac

> sudo npm install -g phonegap

-g stands for globally.
It will install phonegap globally in your system.

Thanks.